# Python - Randomly group 21 names in 7 sets without repeating row

Tags: python, grouping

I would like some help as to how to implement this:

I have 21 names and they are to be **randomly grouped** per set having 3 columns and 7 rows. For the 7 sets, each name must have covered all the rows (rows A-G) and must be randomly assigned to any column per set.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Without much thinking: (1) loop over sets, (2) loop over names, (3) randomly assign column to each name, (4) keep a list/dictionary or counter of previous rows assigned to each name in prior sets and assign the next available row.

Comment: And remove row from consideration for assignment altogether when it's been filled.

Comment: You could also randomly generate 7 groups of 3 to get one set, and then shift rows by 1 and randomly shuffle columns to get the next set.  Your task does not mention that names cannot be matched together across sets, so this should work.